# How to control a timer using Reactive Extensions (C#) without any side-effects?

Tags: c#, timer, system.reactive

I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

1. A button is pressed down.
2. An `interval` is calculated by calling the `GetInterval()` method.
3. The `DoSomething()` method is called immediately.
4. The `DoSomething()` method will be called repeatedly every `interval` milliseconds until the button is released.
5. When the button is pressed again, go to 2.

It could be implemented as follows:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += DoSomething();

//keyDown and keyUp are IObservables created from the button's events
keyDown.Do(_ =>
{
    timer.Interval = GetInterval();
    timer.Start();
    DoSomething();                
});

keyUp.Do(_ =>
{
    timer.Stop();
});
```

I know this code have some problems, but it does not matter. What I'm trying to achieve is to implement this scenario using pure [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg577609.aspx), without any external timers and side effects (other than calling the `DoSomething()` method).

I know of Observable.Timer, but I do not know how to use it in this scenario.

**EDIT:** I can create an `IObservable<int>` containing current values of the `interval`. It will probably help.

Comment: Could you tell what  RX is?

Comment: Editorial: step 5 is really outside of the scope - it is implied that when the button is pushed, 1 will happen.

Comment: @theMayer True. I just wanted to emphasize that the procedure is not a single action and will repeat for each button press.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that an approach using `Select`/`Switch` is going to be better than an approach using `SelectMany`.

In general, when using `SelectMany` you may end up with a memory leak as more and more underlying subscriptions are created. This may not happen in this case due to the `TakeUntil`, but it is worth getting into the habit of avoiding this.

Here's my code:

```
var subscription =
    keyDown
        .Select(kd =>
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                .TakeUntil(keyUp)
                .StartWith(-1L))
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(n => DoSomething());
```

When using the `Switch` you must construct an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` to call `.Switch()` on which takes the latest `IObservable<T>` produced by the `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and flattens it similar to a `SelectMany` but the former disposes of the previous observable and the latter doesn't.

I've also included a `StartWith` that ensures that the sequence immediately produces a value.

Comment: FWIW there's an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229435(v=vs.103).aspx) of `Timer` which lets you specify the delay to the initial signal, eliminating the need for `StartWith`: `Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))`

Comment: @Brandon - AH, yes, I keep forgetting about that one. Cheers.

Comment: Select->Switch is a cleaner approach than SelectMany here, and it also handles any case where you may possibly miss the KeyUp event and subsequently receive a KeyDown. In this situation, SelectMany would now be running two DoSomethings every interval, SelectSwitch will switch to the latest Timer and only run once per interval.

Answer (score 5):

```
keyDown
   .SelectMany(_ => 
       Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
          .TakeUntil(keyUp))
   .Subscribe(_ => DoSomething());
```

This will start an interval on every keydown event. The timer will complete on a keyup event being emited.

Comment: This answer assumes that the interval is constant. It isn't. Furthermore, the timer here will not restart when the button is pressed the second time.

Comment: This sequence doesn't complete. It'll create a new timer when the key is pressed a second time.  And if the interval isn't constant just call a method to determine the duration Observable.Interval(this.GetTimespan())

Comment: If you attach this code to the code that creates observables on the button's events (not given), I believe you will have your answer.

Comment: @JamesHay This sequence does complete, because `TakeUntil` completes, even if its argument never ends.

Comment: TakeUntil only completes the interval. Not the whole sequence.

Comment: You're right. I've misred the location of parentheses.

Comment: One last thing: `Interval` produces the first value after the supplied period. I need to fire the `DoSomething` method immediately, so I'm going to use `Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetInterval()))` instead.